# halfcylinder-Line intersection, matlab

Tags: matlab, geometry

I have the following points making half cylinder.

```
p1 = [7.9463,-1.0200,-9.7586];  % start points(boundary)
pS = [9.1163,-1.0200,-9.5886];  % start points (middle)
p2 = [10.2863,-1.0200,-9.7586]; % start points(boundary)


p3 = [7.9463,-1.78,-9.7586]; % End points(boundary)
pE = [9.1163,-1.78,-9.5886]; % End points (middle)
p4 = [10.2863,-1.78,-9.7586]; % End points (boundary)

r=1.17

and line 
line_=[8,-1,-8,9,-8,-10]; %[P0,P1];
```

%%%%%%% Code partially adopted from

[enter link description here](http://www.mathworks.de/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24484-geom3d/content/geom3d/geom3d/intersectLineCylinder.m)

```
% Starting point of the line
l0 = line_(1:3)';

% Direction vector of the line
dl = line_(4:6)'-line_(1:3)';
```

% Starting position of the cylinder

```
c0 = pS;
```

% Direction vector of the cylinder

dc = pE - PS;

% Radius of the cylinder

r =1.17;

% compute discriminant

delta = B^2 - 4*A*C;

% check existence of solution(s)

if delta<0
    points = zeros(0, 3);
    return; end

[image]

How can I get point of intersection of line and half cylinder.

I'm looking for matlab code of my problem. or a link

What should be

> % Coefficients of 2-nd order equation
>
> A = ???????? B = ???????? C = ??????????

Any guidence please.

Comment: it would be more reader friendly if you can explain how these points make that cylinder and line. I can only assume that the points that make the line follow this logic: (x0,y0,z0,x1,y1,z1) but maybe I'm wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Abstracting from matlab, it looks like it is straightforward to find intersection of any half-cylynder with any line segment...

Line segment can be parametrized as

x_L = x_L0+(x_L1-x_L0)*t, where t changes between 0 and 1, x_L0 and x_L1 - end points (same for y,z).

Half cylynder can be parametrized with two parameters as

z=z0+(z1-z0)*u, u changes between 0 and 1 
(x-x0)^2+(y-y0)^2 = r^2, y>0
(x0,y0 - center of the half circle, z0,z1 - range, assuming circle is lying in x,y plane)

Substitution of x and y into equation for half circle provides square equation for t:
(x_L0+(x_L1-x_L0)*t-x0)^2+(y_L0+(y_L1-y_L0)*t-y0)^2 = r^2
Therefore:

```
    A = (x_L1-x_L0)^2+(y_L1-y_L0)^2;
    B = 2*(x_L0-x0)*(x_L1-x_L0)+2(y_L0-y0)*(y_L1-y_L0);
    C = (x_L0-x0)^2+(y_L1-y_L0)^2-r^2;
    D = B^2-4*A*C;
    if D <0
    %no solution
    else
    t(1) = (-B+sqrt(D))/2/A;
    t(2) = (-B-sqrt(D))/2/A;
    sol=nan(3,2);
    for i=1:2
    if t(i)>0 &&... 
t(i)<1 &&... 
y_L0+(y_L1-y_L0)*t(i)>0 &&... 
z_L0+(z_L1-z_L0)*t(i)>z0 &&... 
z_L0+(z_L1-z_L0)*t(i)<z1  
%solution is within interval of parametrization and y > 0, and z_intersectio nis between z0 and z1
    sol(1,i)=x_L0+(x_L1-x_L0)*t(i);
    sol(2,i)=y_L0+(y_L1-y_L0)*t(i);
    sol(3,i)=z_L0+(z_L1-z_L0)*t(i);
    end;
    end;
```

Comment: I think you either formulating your question wrong or misunderstanding something, since point of intersection does not depend on orientation of the line (which point of line is start and which is end), also there is not clear what do you mean by "intersection in inside direction of cylynder"....

Comment: @ Ilya Kobelevskiy Can you please tell me moreabout analytical formula. I cannot figure out solution. It would be nice if you write some matlab code.

Comment: Check out the edit of my answer, I haven't double checked the math, but this approach will yield correct answer if implemented properly - parametrize line segment, substitute in equation for semi circle, determine intersection points in any, check conditions - that point is within line segment and within z range